# User Inputted CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an app where the user can input their own CSS, and said CSS would then be applied to the webpage. Is there a simple way to do this, or do I have to parse the CSS manually and put manually edit, say, `document.getElementById(elid).style` for `#elid`?

Thanks.

Comment: i think it depends if you want the css to be applied permanently or just in that load of the webpage

Comment: This is a really, really broad question. You're going to have to parse *some* of the CSS, just to check it.

Comment: Define you page in such way that elements have classes. Then it simple a matter of changing stylesheet. E.g. it can be stored per-user and outputted specifically for each user

Comment: This is a really broad question. Can you save the CSS files? Do you want this CSS to apply to any page on the web?

Comment: More info is needed. Do you want someone to upload a css file? Or are they supposed to type css into a form? Will the css be applied to the current page immediately? Or will it be applied to the website permanently? I can think of many more questions... Please be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it would only be a temporary change (Just for that page view) you can modify it using javascript.

```
<script>
function appendCss() {
    var css = document.getElementById('css-input').value;
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innerHTML = css;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
    head[0].appendChild(style)
}
</script>
```

Then you just have to call the function appendCss() when you want the css to take effect.  Once again this only works for that page view, it won't be permenant.

Comment: Also it will be good idea to set up id of style node or store reference to it in code for detach previous style when you call appendCss again and again.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about appending to the body :P

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's good practice, but why not just create a style element?

```
var css = userinputhere;
var stylez = document.createElement("style");
stylez.type = 'text/css';
if (stylez.styleSheet) stylez.styleSheet.cssText = css;
else stylez.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
```

Create the element, set the type property, and then append the `css` to the `cssText` property if the browser supports it, else create a text node and append it.

Note that it is up to you to sanitize and make sure that the user input is safe. Don't forget to append the style to the head tag, either.